# Which edition of ArcGIS for Server and which capacity level?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, enterprise-geodatabase, wfs

I need to define the edition of ArcGIS for Server product to invest for a small scale oil & gas company.

What we need is to be able to:

1. Work on a geodatabase with 2-3 concurrent desktop users while a allowing access to a few more desktop users,
2. Serve maps from geodatabase (and satellite images and documents from the file server) to internal non-GIS users through web browsers and enabling specific tools like querying and basic geoprocessing on the client side.
3. Allow some users feed the geodatabase using their tablets or smartphones,

I read the ArcGIS for Server functionality matrix and got confused. The first part of the document tells me that I need ArcGIS for Server Enterprise Advanced (full product) but the case studies made me think that a workgroup-standard license seems to be enough. 
Similarly I first got the impression that I need the Portal for ArcGIS product to serve any maps (do not want to use cloud) but then I thought ArcGIS for Server alone can be enough for services like WMS, WFS etc..

My company can invest on these products so I do not consider Open Source platforms but just want to make sure that we are not over investing.

Any advise on this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the functionality matrix? It should be easy enough to find, but to be sure that *we* know what you are looking at... Also, what sort of requirements & needs do you have around development of your web/mobile solutions? Are you looking for COTS (configurable solutions) or building your own solution in house? That answer will likely influence your needs around ArcGIS Portal/Online vs. standalone ArcGIS Server.

Comment: [Here](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf) is the link. We will not have advanced developers so we definitely need COTS solutions that can be configured by GIS specialists. Think of a GIS team 2 or 3 in the head office working on an ArcSDE running on SQL, a geodatabase that caan reach up to a few GBs, imagery from file server (around 100 GB) and many documents that will be linked to the features in the database.

Comment: A few more ArcGIS desktop users in some other offices directly accessing Arcsde, several non-GIS users accesing maps from their web browsers. Some users should be able to access the maps, add their own data, save some specific projects from web browsers and and their mobile devices. One important points is we do not want to use the cloud so ArcGIS Online will not be an option.